# GeoNetwork 3.12.9 support for OpenID Connect Authentication protocol

Tags: geonetwork, security

The GeoNetwork 4.x documentation indicates, among several supported authentication modes, the OpenID Connect protocol (https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/4.0.x/en/administrator-guide/managing-users-and-groups/authentication-mode.html?highlight=openid#authentication-openid), that, instead, I can't find within the same section of 3.12.9 release (https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.12.x/en/administrator-guide/managing-users-and-groups/authentication-mode.html?highlight=keycloak#authentication-keycloak).
Is it just a matter of limited documentation, or OpenID Connect is not supported on GeoNetwork 3.12.9?

Answer (score 1):

OpenID Connect isn't supported in GeoNetwork 3 series.

Comment: Could it be back ported, or is it not possible due to Java version etc.

Comment: The policy on GN 3 it's that it doesn't receive new features, just bug fixes and security updates. But if someone has funding for doing the backport it could probably be done. You can find some parties providing commercial support at http://www.osgeo.org/search_profile and looking for GeoNetwork (site not working today)